# Why is $ab+bc+ac = 0$ in some situation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computer-science

This is originally a Computer Science question, but I ran a equation that is too hard to solve. Here goes.

So the problem is quite simple, given positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$, and calculate $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

But here's the problem, if I calculate any of the squares, I will trigger an integer overflow, where the computer have not enough allocated space to save the result.

So the problem gives me an additional condition: the difference between the minimum of the three and the bigger other two is perfect squares.

That said, if $c$ is the smallest of the three. $b-c$ and $a-c$ will both be perfect squares. And the answer itself is an integer, which means $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is also a perfect square.

So, here's what I got so far.

assume $c$ is the smallest of the three.

let $m=\sqrt{a-c}$, and $n=\sqrt{b-c}$, so $2m^2n^2=2ab-2ac-2bc+2c^2$

and $a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b-c)^2-2ab+2ac+2bc$

Organize the two, and I am able to get:

$(a+b-c)^2-2(a-c)(b-c)=a^2+b^2+c^2$

And the answer to this problem simply output: $a+b-c$, so $2(a-c)(b-c)$ must be zero under the given condition.

Here's some sample to test it out.

```
2, 2, 1   - 3
3, 6, 2   - 7
4, 12, 3  - 13
```

And the following is wrong, since $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ is not an integer:

```
2, 5, 1   - 6, which is wrong, should be sqrt(30)
7, 6, 6   - 7, which is wrong, should be 11, here's what I think
          - it violate the clues set by the problem. The problem state
          - the smallest ONE, and the bigger TWO.
```

P.S. I tagged it under `elementary number theory`, if you think it's better off to be somewhere else, comment below. Need more information? Comment below. Thanks!

Comment: What about $a=7,b=6,c=6$, where $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} = 11$ and $a+b-c = 7$?

Comment: EDIT: correct how m and n should be, both missed the square root sign.

Comment: @Cocopuffs There should be only one smallest, as the problem DID NOT state. It is a badly written problem, and another badly written explanation by me.

Comment: Very well. Take $a=12, b=9, c=8$ where $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} = 17$ and $a+b-c = 13$.

Comment: @Cocopuffs Ya, I really want to say it's a false positive. But, since I can't. You win? The problem still remain though, why is it correct under some condition?

Comment: Your samples are wrong.  The first would claim that $(2+1-1)^2-2(2-1)(2-1)=7=2^2+2^2+1^2=9$  The difference is $2c^2$ as I point out below.  It is not true that $2(a-c)(b-c)=0$.  Which factor is zero?

Comment: Certainly, the problem is: $(a+b-c)^2-2(a-c)(b-c)=a^2+b^2+c^2$. It should be: $(a+b-c)^2-2(a-c)(b-c)=a^2+b^2-c^2$

Comment: @RossMillikan As I understood it, the claim in that case is $(2+2-1)^2 = 2^2 + 2^2 + 1^2$..

Comment: ALL: I think I should consider putting this under CS, and simply ask: How to do this without overflow. THOUGH $a = MAX$, $b = MAX$, $c = MAX$, and $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} > MAX$

Comment: I think I should start to put this under trash.

Answer (score 2):

In your question you say:
So the problem gives me an additional condition: the difference between the minimum of the three and the bigger other two is perfect squares.

That said, if c is the smallest of the two. $b−c$ and $a−c$ will both be perfect squares. And the answer itself is an integer, which means $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is also a perfect square.

The second paragraph contradicts the first-the first only guarantees that one of $a-c$ and $b-c$ is a square.  If the numbers are as you say, you will still get overflow of $(a+b-c)^2$, which is greater than $a^2$

Your derivation is incorrect.  $2m^2n^2=2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2=2(a^2-2ac+c^2)(b^2-2bc+c^2)$ which has a term $2a^2b^2$

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I mistyped how m and n should be. And yes, I thought $a+b-c$ will overflow, but as the solution submitted is marked as accepted, I guess it's the design of the question.

Comment: @ShaneHsu:  Under Organize the two, you lost a term $2c^2$.  You need to add that to the left. It is not true that $2(a-c)(b-c)$ is zero.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  True, but the left side has $-c^2$ and the right has $+c^2$

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm just objecting to this line: $2m^2n^2=2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2=2(a^2-2ac+c^2)(b^2-2bc+c^2)$. I assumed that was your correction of the original post, but it is wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  Yes, that was a correction to the original post.  In it, we had $m=a-c$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Ah, didn't realize there was a major edit. Never mind.

Comment: @RossMillikan Here's where I think I am right about organizing it:
$(a+b-c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab-2bc-2ac$ And $2m^2n^2-2c^2=2ab-2bc-2ac$ I can simply substitute it. $(a+b-c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2+2m^2n^2-2c^2$ And here you go, $2m^2n^2-2c^2$ should be zero, which means $2ab-2bc-2ac$ should also be zero.

Comment: @RossMillikan But hell, it's still wrong, and I think the question itself is not constructive. LOL

Comment: @ShaneHsu:  I don't see why you think $a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b-c)^2$  You have found the correction terms, but they do not make zero.

Comment: @RossMillikan That's what I mean by "Hell, it's still wrong" I mean my calculation is correct, but it only happens in VERY VERY special situation. So, yes, the idea is wrong.

Comment: @RossMillikan Well, thanks anyway.